# Issue with modifying environment variables in Jest setupFiles configuration

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

I am encountering an issue with modifying environment variables within Jest's setupFiles configuration. I have a setup file that modifies some environment variables before the tests run. However, when I try to delete or modify the variables within the tests, the changes do not take effect. The values remain the same as in the setup file.

Here is a simplified example of the problem:
set-env-vars.ts

```
process.env.CI = "true";
process.env.CI_PIPELINE_ID = "12345";
process.env.CI_PROJECT_NAME = "gitlab-ci-project";
process.env.CI_PROJECT_PATH = "my/awsome/project";
```

I tried using set-env-vars.ts in `setupFilesAfterEnv` and `setupFiles`.

predefined-var.ts

```
export function EnvProxy(key: string): string {
  if (process.env.CI === "true") {
    return process.env[key]!;
  }

  // indicate that we are not running within a pipeline by
  // returning an empty string
  if (key === "CI") {
    return "";
  }

  // in the case we are not running within a pipeline ($CI is empty)
  // for all other variables we return a dummy value which
  // explicitly describe this state
  return process.env[key] ?? "notRunningInAPipeline";
}

/**
 * This class contains constants for [Gitlab CI predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)
 */
export const PredefinedVariables = {
  CHAT_CHANNEL: EnvProxy("CHAT_CHANNEL"),
  CHAT_INPUT: EnvProxy("CHAT_INPUT"),
  CI: EnvProxy("CI")
}
```

In my test I was using different approaches like:

```
test("empty string if env CI is set", () => {
  jest.replaceProperty(process, "env", {CI: "false"});
  expect(PredefinedVariables.CI).toBe("false");
});
```

or

```
test("empty string if env CI is set", () => {
  process.env.CI = "false"
  expect(PredefinedVariables.CI).toBe("false");
});
```

neither worked. The only test which will work is setting `process.env.CI = "false"` before all imports.

Comment: It’s unclear what PredefinedVariables is (give a [mre]), but unless its CI property is a computed getter there’s certainly no reason to expect the line before could possibly change its value.